# how to get the oldest / earliest year value from a class

Tags: c#, linq

I need to find a way to grab the earliest "year" from my class, right now I have this line

```
var distinctyear = fldF.Select(x => x.MYEAR).Distinct();
```

But this test was with a small simple set of files and folders. So I need to make sure that if there are more than one year in that list(fldF) that I need to get the oldest only from it to set my variable

In this test, fldF had "2019" and "2020" and would want "2019"

There is always a chance that there will be 2 year values in the list, so I always want to get the oldest one.

Comment: What about `fldF.OrderBy(x => x.MYEAR).FirstOrDefault()`?

Comment: `fldF.Select(x => x.MYEAR).Min();`

Comment: Do you need the smallest _year_ or the _x_ with the smallest year?

Comment: @RenéVogt or even `fldF.Min(x => x.MYEAR);`

Comment: This would never happen, but to provide another example, if the list had 1974, 1980, 2019 and 2021, in this example i would need 1974, so i will always want to get the oldest/smallest year from the list.

Comment: @CubanGT What is the data type of `MYEAR`? Why did you use `Distinct` in your code?

Comment: its a string and used that because that was the only thing i found when searching for how to get to the answer and because that list has 4 sets of values and in my current list, i have the following:

Comment: FLD = "CLR" MYEAR = "2019" MDATE = "08-06-2019",   FLD = "HD" MYEAR = "2019" MDATE = "08-06-2019"  , FLD = "PD" MYEAR = "2019" MDATE = "08-01-2019"    In my last test, i had the same as above. but there was one set that had 2020 for the year, so in that case, i got distinct, which gave me 2019 and 2020 and from that i need 2019, for the most part, thru the year, it will alway have just one year, but towards the end of the year and into the new year, there will be a chance for 2 years

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Min`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.min?view=netframework-4.8):

```
var distinctyear = fldF.Select(x => x.MYEAR).Min();
```